# Redis Cluster Distributed Keyslot

Tags: redis

I have a sorted set in redis with many millions of members. Because it is a single set, the members of the set are all located on a single node within my cluster. I'd like to split my set into multiple keys so the members are distributed across the cluster. In the redis documentation, it looks like I can append `{some_value}` to the end of the key that can be used to calculate the keyslot.

```
> CLUSTER KEYSLOT somekey
11058
> CLUSTER KEYSLOT foo{hash_tag}
(integer) 2515
> CLUSTER KEYSLOT bar{hash_tag}
(integer) 2515
```

What I would like to then do is split my `schedules` key into something like `schedules{1}`, `schedules{2}`, `schedules{3}`. But that alone doesn't guarantee that the members will be distributed. If I split the members into many thousands of keys I can be pretty confident that is an even-enough distribution, but I'd really just like to have 1 key per node.

Is there anyway to determine before-hand what to name my key to guarantee it will be distributed evenly across nodes? I can generate random strings until i've found a distribution, but that seems wrong.

[image: keycluster]

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution for your problem, but it's might not be a recommended solution.

> How

First of all, you need a find `N` keys that maps to different slot (`N` is the number of master nodes your Redis Cluster has). A simple but tedious way to do this is to use `redis-cli -c -h host -p port` to log on one of your node, and call `get 1`, `get 2`, `get 3`... to see "1", "2", "3"... are located on different slot:

```
127.0.0.1:7000> get 1
-> Redirected to slot [9842] located at 127.0.0.1:7002
"1"
```

This means key "1" is located on slot 9842.

A programmatic way is to use the [crc16](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-distribution-model) to calculate the slot of a given key.

When you get `N` different keys mapping to different slots, you can use [cluster setslot](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-setslot) command to move these slots to different node.

Then you can split your set into `N` parts, each part uses the keys you got as hash-tag, e.g. `schedules{key1}`, `schedules{key2}`...

At last, you're guaranteed that these `N` part will be located on different nodes.

> Why it's might not be a recommended solution

- It's complicated
- If you add new or remove a node, you need to reallocate your set
- If some one changed the slot-node mapping, some keys might be located on the same node